# Installing MYSQL 5.6.21 using MySQLInstallerConsole.exe and chaning datadir

Tags: mysql, windows, silent-installer

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. This forum has helped me tremendously.

I been looking to install MySQL Server (on Windows) from MYSQL community edition in silent mode with custom datadir. 
I am successfully able to install mysql server with default configs after running following commands.

```
    msiexec /i "mysql-installer-community-5.6.21.1.msi" /qn
```

After you run above command, we need to extract NewManifest.zip file into %appdata%mysql folder

```
    7z.exe" x "%appdata%\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\NewManifest.zip" -o"%appdata%\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Manifest"
```

Once Manifest is extracted, I am trying to use MySQLInstallerConsole to set password.

```
    MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" install server;5.6.21;x64:*:port=3306;passwd=bar -silent
```

While, this has been working perfectly, if I pass datadir option as below, installer console errors out

```
    MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" install server;5.6.21;x64:*:port=3306;passwd=bar:datadir=c:/test -silent
    MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" install server;5.6.21;x64:*:port=3306;passwd=bar;datadir=c:/test -silent
```

THe error "says MySQL Server 5.6.21 - Error parsing option string '/test'"

I tried with both semicolon and colon between passwd and datadir options (Above)

All i need is silently install mysql server using MySQLInstallerConsole with custom setting

```
    port
    password
    datadir
```

I tried many combinations and still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already figured this out by now, but you need to enclose your path in double quotes.

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe install server;5.6.21;x64:*:port=3306;passwd=bar:datadir="c:/test" -silent
```